# Multiple query parameters in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting query parameters like this from an external service:

```
url/?error=someError&error_description=someErrorDescription
```

I've been trying to capture this in my app.js through this routeProvider

```
$routeProvider.when('/:error', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/user.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl as route'
    });
```

but instead of one query parameter I'd need several on the same level. I can do it by splitting the string I am now getting as 'error' but it feels quite dirty.
Is there any other Angular solution for several query strings?

Comment: Maybe `$location.search()`?

Answer (score 0):

Because your route is `url/` everything after is your query.
You can't handle this with the routeProvider, try with $location provider.

Answer (score 0):

use $location:

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('MainCtrl', function($location) {
    this.error = $location.search()['error'];
    this.errorDescription = $location.search()['error_description'];
});
```

and at user.html:

```
{{ route.error }}
{{ route.errorDescription }}
```